# NavigationProperty null on added foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, navigation-properties

Whenever I add a foreign key entity to my previous entity by setting the ForeignKey-ID, the associated object is null.

Let me explain this:
[image]

In a previous step I've set the `AddressId` property to `28` and have saved the entity context by calling `context.SaveChanges()`.

Now why is `AddressId` filled, but `Address` as the NavigationProperty (which should be an `Address` object of the `Address` table where `Address.Id == 28`) is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Frameworks (EF) work this by design.
Updating the foreign key never updates the navigation property.

However, updating the navigation property will update the key. Also note that in this case the `Address` entity should come from the same context. If not `.SaveChanges()` will consider the  `Address` entity as new and try to add it in the database.

As to the question of which method is better, well, it depends!
- Updating the Key is straightforward and is what we have been doing all along using Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) or even plain SQL. So is easier for newcomers to EF to grasp and use.
- Updating the navigation property is where you truly get an object based data model. The code looks cleaner and more readable. However you need to be very careful with the Context. In my little personal experience with EF, I find that trying to update the navigation property brings more complexity than value, especially in a multi-tier architecture where the Context is hidden behind the Data Access layer.

The most important benefit of EF, in my opinion, is in query operations using LINQ-to-Entities. I have compile-time syntax check for my queries and strong typing. I can easily create an object-based result set with multiple levels of children, data-bind ready without any additional code.  I rarely write SQL anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is better, updating the key or updating the entire navigation property?

Answer (score 0):

I sorta *fixed* this by re-creating my entities and reloading then. This seems to work and re-fetch the n:m relationship navigation properties. Weird.

Comment: Yes, that works but at the expense of an extra query to the database.

Comment: if the object in the context already and you set a fk ID EF can easily point to / show the Nav property.  If you access nav property, it would load it to hand it over. I personally use fk Ids only and dont get too carried away with building graphs. When reading, I do look to access the navigation props